# Fast switching between external and internal screen

Tags: gnome, xorg, kde, display-settings

Is there a solid way of using either X directly or KDM/GDM/KDE/Gnome to quickly switch between an external screen and modify the screen layout accordingly? I'm stealing the inspiration from Windows 7's +P functionality, where a central popup shows 4 different possible layouts: only external, duplicate, only internal screen, extend desktop.

I can switch between any (or at least most) of these by using the Nvidia control panel (and if I was using the open source drivers, through the KDE X screen configuration option screen, and something similar for Gnome). I would like a faster way to just switch output, without having to go through billions of menus (ok, slightly exaggerated, but still... you get the point)

Answer (score 1):

With open source drivers, you can use the [`xrandr`](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.xhtml) command line utility to modify the screen layout. Bind a key or menu entry to a small script that calls `xrandr` if you like. For the configurations you describe, the commands would be something like

```
xrandr --output external
xrandr --output external --same-as internal
xrandr --output internal
xrandr --output external --left-of internal
```

with names that may well not be `internal` and `external` but `DVI-0` and `VGA-0` or something else; run `xrandr` to see what you have. You can write a more substantial script that parses the output of `xrandr`, for example if you want to have a key that cycles between a few predefined settings.

You can do something similar with [`nvidia-settings`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/nvidia-settings.1.html) for the Nvidia proprietary driver. The documentation isn't very precise; your best bet may be to set up a few different configurations through the GUI and switch between them using `nvidia-settings --config`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a [X Resize, Rotate and Reflect Extension (RandR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xrandr) GUI, [here's a list](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2#GUIs), I don't much about them, though.